# Actionscript change default coordinate

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a sprite inside another sprite
SpriteB is inside SpriteA
I would like to change the default coordinate(top left corner) to say 250,10
When `SpriteB.x = 0`, `SpriteB.y = 0` puts SpriteB to 250,10 in SpriteA
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `transform.matrix` property of the sprite:

```
SpriteB.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 250, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

any child is referenced by the coordinate system of the parent, therefore if spriteB is contained in SpriteA, the x and y of SpriteA are added to that of spriteB when position is worked out.

all you have to do is `SpriteB.x=250; SpriteB.y=10;` and it will work.

Comment: just to clarify, that code would go in SpriteA, NOT in SpriteB, and you would have to replace SpriteB with the actual instance name of your SpriteB instance.